# Trying to get the property of a non-object in laravel

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables: `user` and `student`. The field `username` from `user` is a foreign key as `login_id` in `student`. I have created eloquent relationships in each model, but when I try to access `Auth::user()->student->id` it gives me:

> Trying to get the property of a non-object.

Student Model:

```
public function user()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('user','login_id');
}
```

User Model:

```
public function student(){
    return $this->hasOne('student')
}
```

ProfileController.php

```
<?php
class ProfileController extends BaseController
{
    public function showinfo()
    {
        if (Auth::check())
        {
            $user_id = Auth::user()->username;
            $student_id = Auth::user()->student->id;
        }
    }
}
```

Above noted error occurs when I try to log in.

Comment: No, now I get another error: BadMethodCallException
HELP
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::student()

Answer (score 0):

You should check first if the user who login has student, so i would suggest

```
$student = Auth::user()->student;
if($student) $student_id = $student->id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$student_id = Auth::user()->student->id;
```

If it doesnt contain value, then you get that error. Try using isset, or empty, depends on what you like.

Only with many to many relations you use the `( )`.

**Example:**

```
$user_companies = Auth::user()->companies();

foreach($user_companies as $company)
```